# Create an object in memory pointed to by a void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, sizeof, memcpy

If I have a void* to some chunk of free memory and I know there is at least sizeof(T) available, is there any way to create an object of type T in that location in memory?

I was just going to create a T object on the stack and memcpy it over, but it seems like there must be a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with templates or c++11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use placement new for it:

```
#include <new>

void *space;
new(space) T();
```

Remember to delete it before you free the memory:

```
((T*)space)->~T();
```

Do not create object on stack and memcpy it over, its not safe, what if the object has its address stored in a member or a member of a member?

Comment: Awesome!  I knew there must be an easy way to do it.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First, just knowing that `sizeof(T)` amount of memory is available is not sufficient. In addition you must know that the void pointer is aligned correctly for the type of object you want to allocate. Using misaligned pointers can cause either a performance hit or a crashing application, depending on your platform.

However if you know that free memory and alignment are right, you can use placement new to construct your object there. However be aware that you also have to explicitly destruct it in that case. For example:

```
#include <new>      // for placement new
#include <stdlib.h> // in this example code, the memory will be allocated with malloc
#include <string>   // we will allocate a std::string there
#include <iostream> // we will output it

int main()
{
  // get memory to allocate in
  void* memory_for_string = malloc(sizeof(string)); // malloc guarantees alignment
  if (memory_for_string == 0)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  // construct a std::string in that memory
  std::string* mystring = new(memory_for_string) std::string("Hello");

  // use that string
  *mystring += " world";
  std::cout << *mystring << std::endl;

  // destroy the string
  mystring->~string();

  // free the memory
  free(memory_for_string);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```